# How does the skin color follow Gaussian distribution in YCBCR?

Tags: image-processing, probability-distribution, normal-distribution

I am still new to image processing and machine intelligence. I wanted to make a Python program that can isolate an image of a hand from the background to detect a specific hand gesture, so I came to [this paper (Hand Gesture Based Recognition And Voice Conversion System For Physically Disabled People)](https://www.iosrjournals.org/iosr-jece/papers/Conf.MAM-2019/Volume-1/6.%2037-41.pdf), and the writer states in this paper that:

> Pixels of skin color in YCbCr color space satisfies Gaussian
> distribution. Experiments show that using the single Gaussian model
> (SGM) to segment the gesture image is effective and its computational
> complexity is small

I don't understand how the skin color follows the Gaussian distribution in YCbCr colour space. If so, what's the variance and mean of skin color in that space?